# Callout Error from Batch Job

Tags: apex, rest-api, batch, class

I have a batch job from which I'm doing callout to wave analytics and based on the response I'm updating one checkbox field on Account.

When I execute the batch with the size of 100, I'm getting **First error: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out** error, even though I'm doing all DML operations at the end.

When I'm executing a batch with the size of 1, I'm getting **AsyncApexExecutions Limit Exception** exception as I have a lot of records.

Batch Class:

```
List<Account> accountListToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        for(account accObj : accountlist){
            if(accObj.Data__c != null){
                system.debug('>>> accObj... '+accObj);
                List<string> groupList = accObj.Data__c.split(';');
                List<string> parentGrouping = new List<string>();
                
                for(string str : groupList){
                    List<string> subList = str.split(':');
                    parentGrouping.add(subList[0]);
                }
                
                string stri = '[';
                Boolean isFirst = true;
                for(string st : parentGrouping){
                    if(isFirst){
                        stri += '"'+st+'"';
                        isFirst = false;
                    }else{
                        stri += ',"'+st+'"';
                    }
                }
                stri += ']';
                system.debug('>>> stri... '+stri);
                
                string query = 'q = load "' +label.Lense_Id +'";q = filter q by \'Market\' == "Low";q = filter q by \'Postcod.Postcode\' == "' + +accObj.Zip__c + '";q = filter q by \'Categor.Category\' in' + +stri+ ';q = foreach q generate \'Categor.Category\' as \'Categor.Category\';q = limit q 1;';
                
                ConnectApi.LiteralJson queryresult = ConnectApi.Wave.executeQuery(query);
                string response = queryresult.json;
                SuperClass sc = (SuperClass)JSON.deserialize(response, SuperClass.class);
                Results resList = sc.results;
                List<Records> recList = resList.records;
                
                if(recList.size() > 0){
                    Account accountObj = new Account();
                    accountObj.Id = accObj.Id;
                    accountObj.CustomCheckBox__c = true;
                    accountListToUpdate.add(accountObj);
                }else{
                    Account accountObj = new Account();
                    accountObj.Id = accObj.Id;
                    accountObj.CustomCheckBox__c = false;
                    accountListToUpdate.add(accountObj);
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
        if(accountListToUpdate.size() > 0){
            update accountListToUpdate; 
        }
```

Comment: What is this line doing `update accObj;` inside for loop?

Comment: I was trying to do something else and I forgot to remove it while pasting here, but in my actual batch class it's not present.

Comment: Could a call out be called in a Batch? I do not think so.

Comment: Yes, we can. We need to implement a Database.AllowsCallouts interface

Comment: From a quick Google there is https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005eWcQAI. Perhaps that API call counts as a DML?

Comment: I also believe so, but couldn't find any documentation, What alternative approach I should have for this?

Comment: general solutions to these issues involve delegating work to asynchronous transactions - either queueable or platform events